# Uploading videos to ScreenCast.com in C++

Tags: c++, http, upload, youtube-api

I need to write a C/C++ program that uploads videos to [ScreenCast.com](http://screencast.com). For uploading videos to YouTube there is a [great manual](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading.html#Direct_uploading) that explains how it can be done with an http request. I can't find something like that about Screencast.

Maybe someone has experience with this or some related tasks.  I'm quite new to programming, and would be very grateful for any advice or thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any API is given for developers so that you can write your own app in your own language to do stuffs you like. First make sure that let you do, what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you using any screencast.com features that would particularly drive a desire to use them to store your files?  I ask because I used it once and "ran out of bandwidth" (they didn't give much, at least at the time).  So an embedded video I had there stopped being available on my site, which I only found out about after-the-fact.  Nowadays I use YouTube HD and my own hosting.  If you are using a programmatic API instead of going through Jing/etc. then I'd just be curious why you'd use their hosting service at all...?

Comment: It's my task, I already did uploader to YouTube, now I have to do the one to screencast.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is that for now it is impossible. I have contacted screencast.com support, and they told me that they are going to make a puplic API somewhen in future